# Accessing variables without using the dataValues object in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Was just wondering why I can access attributes returned from Sequelize, even though those values *don't seem to exist* on the object I'm referencing.

For example:

Sequelize response:

```
[
    Job {
        dataValues: {
            id: 2,
            title: 'some job'
        },
        // ... more model variables
    },
    Job {
        dataValues: {
            id: 3,
            title: 'another job'
        },
        // ... more model variables
    }
]
```

Given the above response I can access the title value of the first entry as `result[0].title` **or** `result[0].dataValues.title`. But if I use a sequel function to format the createdAt `col` it **isn't** available without using `.dataValues`:

```
exports.test = (req, res, next) => {
    Job.findAll({
        attributes: [
            'title', 
            'createdAt', 
            [Sequelize.fn('date_format', Sequelize.col('job.createdAt' ), '%d/%m/%y'), 'date'] // *Only* accessible with inside the dataValues object
        ]
    }).then(results => {    
        console.log(results[0].date);              // undefined
        console.log(results[0].dataValues.date);   // '09/06/21'

        res.status(200).send();
    }).catch(err => next(err));
}
```

I'm just interested to know how, **a)** these variables are accessible without referencing the `dataValues` object, and **b)** why the result of the format function isn't.

I've unfortunately not been able to spot the answer in the Sequelize docs, so would appreciate it if someone can enlighten me or point me to an answer!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of someone with more knowledge, I *think* it's down to the Sequelize object providing custom getters.

`console.log(Object.keys(results[0].__proto__));` outputs Sequelize methods including `_customGetters`.

I can't work out how to view them in any more detail, but I think that explains why I can access the variables outside of the `dataValues` object.

Maybe that limited amount of info will be of use to someone else if they also struggle to get their head round this :)